# Canon 60D flash problem in low light

Tags: canon, low-light, canon-60d, popup-flash

I have bought Canon 60D two days ago .

My problem is...

I have to press forced flash button before capturing first photo in low light .

But the thing I dont understand is ..

From flash setting if I have set flash firing enable then shouldn't it open automatically ?  Why do I need that forced flash button ?

p.s. the flash I am talking about is the forced flash .

p.p.s. I am not facing this kind of problem [I cannot open the internal flash on my Canon 60D camera; how do I fix it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/i-cannot-open-the-internal-flash-on-my-canon-60d-camera-how-do-i-fix-it?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flash will not automatically activate in all camera modes as some leave the decision up to the user when you are exercising a degree of manual control.  If you are in manual for example it will only fire when you specifically turn it on by popping it up.

More specifically for the 60D, on page 129 of your manual it indicates

> In Creative Zone modes, just press the [popup flash] button to
>   pop-up the built-in flash. To
>   retract the built-in flash,
>   push it back down with your fingers.
>
> In Basic Zone modes (except 3 of them), the
>   built-in flash will pop-up and fire automatically in low-light and backlit conditions. The CA mode enables
>   you to select between automatic flash firing and flash
>   on/off
>   (p.61)

Comment: okay .. so there is not any problem there .. I need to press that button when I need flash in manual mode ..right?

Comment: Right, your camera is behaving properly.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t want to sound like a father doing a speech but the Canon Manual is a great source of information. I read mine (which is the same Camera you have) like 4 times to understand some functionality of the camera. I found it the best way to achieve the best of that baby.

Answer (score 0):

Set your camera to automatic mode, if you need an easy solution to this problem. It makes the camera think for you. 
This is not how to become a professional photographer, but it will use the flash in generally the right situations.